# C Function name highlighting in notepad++

Tags: c, syntax-highlighting, notepad++

Does anyone know how to highlight the function name inside notepad++? I was able to use style configurator to set up syntax highlighting, but there is no option to highlight function name.

Comment: Why is this tagged C? Why not COBOL (does COBOL lack functions?) ???

Comment: @pmg, He asked for function highlighting in C if you read the title

Comment: @Jesus: so my answer is "by running UB programs until that happens: use, for instance, `i = i++;` in the UB programs".

Comment: @pmg, ... are you trying to make some kind of point?

Comment: Point is: tagging this question with `c` is 'over-tagging'; kinda like tagging it with `english` or `computer` ...

Comment: well the question was about notepad++ and syntax highlighting in c so i dont really see a problem with that.... but to each his own

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done. There is no option to highlight function names.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a custom lexer for C/C++ and import it as DLL. After that you'll have to change .c extension for the standard lexer to something like .c_std, and set your lexer to lex .c files.

It is not an easy task, but it can be done.

Answer (score -1):

Just takes listing the functions:
Settings -> Style Configurator
Select C on left, select TYPE WORD in middle,
at bottom right paste the names of the functions.
Select the Foreground color you want.
Save & Close

Comment: Try to add all Windows API functions there and also not go mad while manually adding each new function you ever write.